# Why 2fa enable doesn't work with jetstream?

Tags: laravel, fortify

I inherited a project with laravel jetstream v2.7 and need a middleware that goes to check if 2fa is enabled and if not redirect it to a view where you are forced to enable 2fa.

The middleware:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        if (is_null(Auth::user()->two_factor_secret)) {
            return redirect(route('2fa'));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

and the view:

```
@if (Laravel\Fortify\Features::canManageTwoFactorAuthentication())
         <div class="mt-10 sm:mt-0">
             @livewire('profile.two-factor-authentication-form')
         </div>
    @endif

    @if(auth()->user()->two_factor_secret)
         <a href="dashboard" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary backmobile">Next</a>
    @endif
```

and web.php:

```
// 2FA
    Route::get('2fa', function () {
        return view('auth1.2fa');
    })->name('2fa');

    // Go to dashboard if registration is completed
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['registration_completed', 'verified',          'checkSuspendedUser','has2FaEnabled']], function () {
```

The problem is that clicking the button that should enable 2fa does not work. The same technique works in the custom profile settings view. Why?

I want to force 2fa enablement via middleware verification

Comment: In addition to fixing this, you might want to use the inherited/mixed in `TwoFactorAuthenticatable#hawEnabledTwoFactorAuthentication()`